# Does the _T Macro effect std::string constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I inherited some old code which needs to stay multibyte/unicode compatible. It currently uses the `_T()` macro for this. I was wondering if `std::string`s are introduced, is `_T()` still needed?

e.g

```
std::string foo(_T("hello"));
```

Or is it now redundant?

Comment: Hmm, won't this fail to compile if `_T` expands to a wide char type?

Comment: It depends how your project is compiled regarding UNICODE mode or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not only unneeded. It's wrong. The `_T` macro expands to convert the string literal to a wide character (`wchar_t`) string literal if `UNICODE` is defined. However, the `std::string` constructor never expects a wide character string (`const wchar_t*`). It always expects `const char*`.

What you might do, if you were still concerned about this sort of thing (compiling for both Unicode and ANSI versions of the WinAPI), is define a new type based on `std::basic_string`

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
```

And then this would be correct:

```
tstring foo(_T("hello"));
```

Answer (score 3):

`_T` will not help here at all: the code will fail to compile if `_T` expands to using `wchar_t` instead of `char`.

If you need to stay in the `TCHAR` madness, you're best off defining your own `tstring` type, and consistently using that instead of `std::string`:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;

tstring foo(_T("Hello"));
```

Remember that `std::string` is just an alias for "`std::basic_string` for `char`s." Then there's `std::wstring`, alias for "`std::basic_string` for `wchar_t`s." What you want is "`std::basic_string` for `TCHAR`s", so create an alias for it.

Answer (score 2):

`_T` is a VC++ macro which expanded to nothing when `UNICODE` is not defined and expands to `L` when unicode is defined.

so if `UNICODE` is not defined, it is completely redundant,  as

```
std::string foo(_T("hello"));
```

turns into

```
std::string foo("hello");
```

But it `UNICODE` **is** defined, the expression is expanded into

```
std::string foo(L"hello");
```

which will fail to compile, as `std::string` has no constructor which gets `const wchar_t*` as argument.

So, if `UNICODE` is not defined, you can safely remove the `_T` macro. if it is defined, you need to refactor your code, probably move to `std::wstring` instead.